# Access protocol extensions with generics declared in a framework

Tags: swift, generics, frameworks, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

Can we access protocol extensions implemented in a framework outside the framework? I mean suppose there is a target say "Framework" in which I declared a protocol and implemented protocol extension.
Now if I try to access this protocol outside the framework it asks me to reimplement the protocol methods.
Can we share the extension implemented in the framework?

```
func createObject<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type, filterPredicate: NSPredicate, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObject
```

Thanks

Ankit

Comment: You probably have access control set up incorrectly, but without seeing the actual code it's impossible to tell for sure. Did you mark the extension methods using the same access control modifiers as the other methods that are visible outside the framework?

Comment: @DávidPásztor all the methods, protocols and extensions are public

Comment: @DávidPásztor added sample code the probem seems to be because of generics, normal methods work fine